# Remove Gmail account in android 5.0.1 galaxy s4

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I wanna remove an old gmail from my s4 . But every time go to setting and tap Google.  The settings app stop running and return me to my home page.  So I could be even get to the options. I've tried removing through the Google app. I'd open the email I want to remove.  Tap account manager.  It'll take me to Google account and add account.  When I tap Google it does the same thing.  It'll say " unfortunately ,settings has stopped." Could someone please help show me how to remove the Gmail account from my phone .  Without having to delete it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can remotely remove a Google account from a device by using [here](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity) link.

1. Log-in to Google with the account you wish to remove
2. Choose the device from where you wish to remove the account
3. Click on 'Remove'

This should help you remove your account. Also, please note that it is not possible to just remove GMail from a device. If a Google service from an account is to be terminated, the full account should be detached from the device.